# Search Multiple value with all columns in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have store the serialized value in a column like

```
a:3:{i:0;s:6:"land_r";i:1;s:11:"mixed_use_r";i:2;s:3:"prs";}
```

Am going to search these columns with multiple values given from user like

```
residentialSelect[]=land_r&residentialSelect[]=mixed_use_r&residentialSelect[]=prs
```

I have to search this post value in all the column that contained serialized value.

The scenario:
1. New post save: The multiple select dropdown to store the serialized value in db first
2. Search post: The multiple select dropdown to search and show the respective post.

Please let me know if am not explained properly.

Comment: You haven't explained this properly. Do you have the string saved as a column and want to do a search within it? If so, change the way you are saving data from scratch.

Comment: What code have you written so far? What error did you get? This website is not meant to ask us to write the code for you.

Comment: Hi guys, Am really sorry for not in detail. I have designed the database at present its working with single value store in a column like 'land_r' in column name 'type'. But now I have to store multi-value from dropdown select, so serialized and store in that 'type' column. So everything fine now. But when I planned to search, Am not sure how to write the mysql code, that is, Am having multiple value from dropdown, So I need to search that values in table which I already store in serialize from.

Comment: It is generally a better idea to store multiple values in multiple columns, or rows. SQL is very good at finding exact matches in columns and then piecing result set together, but that can't be done in this case. I suggest you look into related records, specifically one-to-many and many-to-many.

Comment: Yes, thats good idea. Thanks @BertPeters